# LINQ RowNumber, Aggregate (Sum) and GroupBy

Tags: linq, row-number

I have an SQL code like;

```
Select GroupName, sum(LineAmount) as Total, WeekNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by WeekNumber order by sum(LineAmount) desc) as RowNum
from
    Invoices
where
    month(InvoiceDate)=month(getdate())
group by
    GroupName,WeekNumber
```

I would like to convert this to LINQ, but no luck. I am using LINQ to Object. Any help  would be appreciated.
TIA

EDIT : Here is some sample data, and the expected result.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int LineAmount { get; set; }
    public int WeekNum { get; set; }
}

   List<Invoice> theData = new List<Invoice>();
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "A", LineAmount = 1, WeekNum = 1});
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "A", LineAmount = 2, WeekNum = 1 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "A", LineAmount = 3, WeekNum = 1 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "A", LineAmount = 2, WeekNum = 2 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "A", LineAmount = 3, WeekNum = 2 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "A", LineAmount = 4, WeekNum = 2 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "B", LineAmount = 4, WeekNum = 1 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "B", LineAmount = 3, WeekNum = 1 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "B", LineAmount = 7, WeekNum = 2 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "B", LineAmount = 6, WeekNum = 2 });
    theData.Add(new Invoice { GroupName = "B", LineAmount = 5, WeekNum = 2 });
```

[image]

I have removed "where" from my first query as its not a problem at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theData
.GroupBy(g => new {g.GroupName, g.WeekNum}, (key, gg) => new {key.GroupName, key.WeekNum, Total = gg.Sum(g => g.LineAmount)})
.GroupBy(g => g.WeekNum, (weekNum, gg) => gg.OrderByDescending(g => g.Total).Select((g,i) => new {g.GroupName, g.Total, g.WeekNum, RowNum = i}))
.SelectMany(g => g)
```

Comment: `RowNum = i` should be `RowNum = i + 1` to give the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Serg, your solution gives me the expected result. And I have found a solution as-well. I have no thoughts which one performs best! Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: @bsaglamtimur They a more or less same, and choice is a matter of personal preference and readability. I, for one, don't like nesting queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the language you need it in. Here is the code in C#

```
int index = 0;
var filteredInvoices = (from i in invoices
where i.InvoiceDate.Month == DateTime.Now().Month
group i by new { i.GroupName, i.WeekNumber }
into ig
select new {i.GroupName, Total = ig.Sum(i => i.LineAmount), i.WeekNumber, RowNum = ++index}).OrderByDescending(n => n.Total);
```

filteredInvoices should have the result that you want. Also I am assuming that the i.InvoiceDate is of type DateTime.

Comment: I have edit my question. Can you please review your answer based on my sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Serg Rogovtsev answer gives me expected result. And the below code is what I have done. Don't know which performs better, but results are same.

```
(theData.GroupBy(f => new { f.GroupName, f.WeekNum})
                .Select(r => new {r.Key.WeekNum, r.Key.GroupName, Total = r.Sum(f => f.LineAmount)}))
                .GroupBy(r => new {r.WeekNum}).SelectMany(
                    g =>
                    g.OrderByDescending(f => f.Total).Select(
                        (f, index) => new { f.GroupName, f.Total, f.WeekNum, Ix = index + 1 }))
```